# Boost Hana : basic_type and type, why do we need a relationship between them

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I don't understand why hana must use `basic_type`. I mean, I understand basically how it works, but I do not see the usefulness of using `type`and `basic_type`. Why just developed a "simple" `type` is not enough? Why make some magic like `typeImpl::_` with `_` that inherits from `basic_type`

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/fwd/type.hpp#L40

Comment: `This is usually not a problem, except when T or U should not be instantiated.` So, it is an optimization ?